# fluent ui nortstar FormDropdown make it required field

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

how can we make the the dropdown in the Nortstar Form as a required field?
is it possible to do so ?
in the Fluent ui Form for the textarea and input component we have required Field so onsubmit it validates the input [Form shows to fillout for required fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC5L9.png)
[https://codesandbox.io/s/zgpqse?module=/example.js](https://input%20field%20with%20required%20props)

But for dropdown we don't have anything as such. how do we validate the Dropdown with required field?

we can disable the submit button based on hooks but it would be good if we have a required field
[https://codesandbox.io/s/cokfqy?module=/example.js](https://Dropdown%20inside%20Form)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: in the repo [Form with input textboxes as required](https://codesandbox.io/s/zgpqse?module=/example.js) when we click on submit button if we have a required field it doesnt submit the form, but when we have a dropdown how to handle required scenario 
[form with dropdown](https://codesandbox.io/s/cokfqy?module=/example.js) this the repo for dropdown inside form

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Post your code here and any errors or exceptions you might be getting.